# How to customise infoWindow content from kmlLayer

Tags: google-maps

I'm using a Wordpress plugin that adds `<georss:point>` data to the standard RSS feed at the end of each `<item>`.

When added to a Google map as a `kmlLayer`, it all works fine, displaying the `<title>` and `<description>` fields from the RSS feed by default.

However, I want to display other data from the RSS feed as well e.g. a link back to the original post, and an image. I've added `<author><name>my name</name></author>` as an experiment, added just before the `<georss:point>` - but it doesn't display in the overlay.

Does my feed have to formatted exactly as per:

```
{
author: {
email: "nobody@google.com",
name: "Mr Nobody",
uri: "http://example.com"
},
description: "description",
id: "id",
infoWindowHtml: "html",
name: "name",
snippet: "snippet"
}
```

in order to customise the `infoWindow` content, or is there a way to get extra data from the RSS feed and manipulate the content before the `infoWindow` displays?

For info here's the feed output:

```
<item>
    <title>Helen Robotham profiled on Italian Vogue</title>
    <link>http://blogs.fashion.arts.ac.uk/snapshot/2010/03/22/helen-robotham-profiled-on-italian-vogue/</link>
    <comments>http://blogs.fashion.arts.ac.uk/snapshot/2010/03/22/helen-robotham-profiled-on-italian-vogue/#comments</comments>

    <pubDate>Mon, 22 Mar 2010 09:36:07 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>alastair</dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.fashion.arts.ac.uk/snapshot/?p=1746</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[MA Fashion Artefact alumna Helen Robotham has a detailed profile on vogue.it, complete with biography and gallery. Helen graduated in 2009 and last May won the Fashion Fringe at Covent Garden Accessories Award. View course information]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-1747" src="http://blogs.fashion.arts.ac.uk/snapshot/files/2010/03/vogue-it-robotham-469x288.jpg" alt="" width="469" height="288" /></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.fashion.arts.ac.uk/courses/postgraduate/ma_fashion_artefact.htm">MA Fashion Artefact</a> alumna Helen Robotham has a detailed <a href="http://www.vogue.it/en/talents/graduated-from/2010/03/helen-robotham">profile on vogue.it</a>, complete with biography and gallery. Helen graduated in 2009 and <a href="http://www.fashion.arts.ac.uk/snapshot/2009/05/helen-robotham-wins-fashion-fringe/">last May won</a> the Fashion Fringe at Covent Garden Accessories Award.</p>]]></content:encoded>
        <wfw:commentRss>http://blogs.fashion.arts.ac.uk/snapshot/2010/03/22/helen-robotham-profiled-on-italian-vogue/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
    <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
    <author><name>name</name></author>
    <georss:point>45.4636889 9.1881408</georss:point>
    <georss:featurename>Milan, Italy</georss:featurename>
    <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/74/228310988_33a56d0108_o.jpg" />
</item>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the KML Feature details section could help you:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#KMLFeatureDetails